# WrapPanel in a ListView (Metro)

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have the following code in a Metro app. The listview binds up to a list of objects. My problem is that the WrapGrid assigns them equal width. But some Titles are longer then others so width should be set width to Auto. But this dont work.. anyone have any idea?

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapGrid ItemWidth="250" ItemHeight="80" MaximumRowsOrColumns="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

The key point here is MaximumRowsOrColumns property. Have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not the WrapGrid, but the ListView itself through the ListViewItem/ItemContainerStyle that makes them same size. I don't think there really is a workaround for that though. You could use your own ItemsControl and custom panel or calculate the desired size of each item and based on that - put the items in something like a VariableSizedWrapGrid, setting RowSpan/ColumnSpan appropriately to match that desired size. Other than that - you can either make all items wide enough to fit everything or simply clip the content and display the full strings in the detailed view once the user clicks an item.